# Sending Coordinates to Google App engine

Tags: android, google-maps, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on an android side project where I have set up my website on google Cloud platform, I am also using Google App engine and setup my database on Google Datastore.

My website consists of a map where I can create fences and send the coordinates of the fences to the app. I have maps activity on my android app and I am trying to figure out how to send the GPS location / coordinates of the mobile to the server every few mins.

So that the I can be able to see the location of the mobile on my website map. It is basically how to track a user. Can anyone please let me know if there is a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: And what's the problem? What did you try to do?

Comment: @pengrad - I am trying to figure out how can I solve this issue. There are other solutions which use my SQL database to do this. But I am not able to figure out a way to do it on data store.

Comment: you take location from map activity and send it to server.

Comment: as @pengrad says You should treat this location like any other info you send to your server, just retrieve the location and sent it to whatever API you have on your server. It's not really clear what your issue is, if you are looking for an actual implementation i suggest you google the problem, there are plenty of examples and tutorials it.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, what @pengrad told was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here that are independent of the underlying architecture you are using currently:

- **Polling**
- **Sending Broadcast**

In the first strategy the server (Google App Engine) shall poll the mobile devices at specific time interval. You can find the code for that easily online in the choice of your language. This would fetch the location of the mobile devices which you can store in the datastore and display on the map of your website.

In the second strategy you can put the *sendBroadcast()* code/method in your android code. This would enable the device to send the location to the server and you can store them in the datastore and display them on the map.

Hope this Helps!!